# Animation breaking text

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

I really hope i'm asking this in the correct place, and in the correct way. I'm having problems with animating a bootstrap progress bar.

It all works quite well, but unfortunately at 93% it breaks the font above. Any values below 93% have no issue.

I would greatly appreciate if anybody could assist me in this matter. Maybe i'm taking the wrong approach altogether and have seriously overlooked something.

You can see the problem here http://www.codeply.com/go/txyCbqQ9P8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cheated and simply did this:

```
<span class="bar-width" style="position:absolute!important; margin-left: -30px;">95%</span>
```

Seems to work for me.

Comment: It only fixed the top level one, the second level is still breaking, but thank you for answering !

Comment: The top one is the only one breaking for me, if that's the case, apply the -> style="position:absolute!important; margin-left: -30px;" to all the spans

Comment: Changing the position to absolute and adding top: -25px; right:10px; did the trick perfectly !! Thank you !!